# Ti.MEDIA.ShowCamera does not show camera on Android OS 6

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am unable to bring up the camera using Appcelerator in Android 6.0 using Ti.MEDIA.ShowCamera(...).  I'm doing a basic Proof of Concept app for Android and iOS.  It works fine in iOS and on Android 4, 5, and 5.1.  I'm using the latest Appcelerator SDK: 5.1.2.GA and have tested on an actual Nexus 6 running 6.0.0 and also on the Genymotion Nexus 6 Emulator running 6.0.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think that you have been hit by the new permissions for Android 6.0. You can see more in the [Titanium 5.1.0 sample app](http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2015/11/titanium-5-1-0-sample-app/) - specifically in the [permissions.js file](https://github.com/appcelerator-developer-relations/appc-sample-ti510/blob/master/app/controllers/permissions.js)

Struggling with this myself at the moment :-)

***Edit:***

*I have not been able to use any emulators (Genymotion or Android emulators coming with Android Studio 2.0 beta) to work correctly with the new permissions etc. for Android 6.0. I had to buy a device the other day - and now I have fixed and tested the issues in my app :-)*

*I did use several days to try and get a decent test environment using emulators. But apparently all of that is a little too early for Android 6.0 :-(*

/John

Comment: Thanks @JohnDalsgaard, I implemented some permissions checks and could indeed grant permission and show the camera but not save it for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

From android 5.4, android ask these permission at runtime. So you first need to ask user for the permission. If he grant the permission the only camera will be available to use.
You can use the following code.

```
if (Ti.Media.hasCameraPermissions()) {
                    logicToShowCamera(e);//Write showCamera related logic here....
}else{
     Ti.Media.requestCameraPermissions(function(obj) {
     if (obj.success) {
           logicToShowCamera(e);
     } else {
           alert('Please Provide permission first');
            }
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any SDK 5.1 features you could go back to 5.0.2 or so. Then you don't need the new Android 6 permissions.

I've used the new permissions on a Nexus 4 with Android 6 (CyanogenMod) and I always get false when asking for the permission again after allowing it. Going back with the Ti SDK solved the problem.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and actually rolled back to 5.0.3. It worked as expected (showed the camera and saved to the device) in the Genymotion Nexus 6 emulator running Android 6 but has varying results on actual android devices. For some reason on a real Nexus 6 running Android 6 it calls what appears to be a tiny modal alert labeled **Camera** with action buttons.  On a Moto X running Android 5.1 it successfully shows the camera, appears to take a picture, but does not save to the device.  This is most frustrating, anybody have any ideas?  Of course it works perfectly on iOS devices :/